# How to redirect user back to index.php after checkout page?

Tags: php

How do I prevent the user to return back to the payment page even after checking out? Currently, after user has checkout, and when I click on the browser back button, the user is still able to return back to the payment page with all info still on the form. How do I redirect the user back to the main page such that after the user has checkout, and when they click on the back button, instead of going back to the payment page, they will be redirected back to the main page(index.php) instead?

Currently, under the saveOrderToTable function, I am calling the session array that store all the product user has purchased. I am able to delete the array once the button has been submitted but not the value in the payment form.

My current payment page code:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>PAYMENT PAGE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header_footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/process_payment.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>      
    <?php
        include "navbar.inc.php";
    ?>

    <article class="formvalidateOutput">
        <?php
        $key = 'qkwjdiw239&&jdafweihbrhnan&^%$ggdnawhd4njshjwuuO';
        // Constants for accessing our DB:
        define("DBHOST", ""); 
        define("DBNAME", ""); 
        define("DBUSER", ""); 
        define("DBPASS", "");  
        $custname = $custemail = $custnumber = $streetadd = $blknumber = $unitnumber = $zipcode = $deldate = $deltime = $ccname = $ccnumber = $expdate = $ccvnumber = $errorMsg = "";
        $success = true; 

        if (empty($_POST["custname"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "First name is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $custname = sanitize_input($_POST["custname"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/", $custname)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a proper first name.<br>";     
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $custname = sanitize_input($_POST["custname"]);    
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["custemail"])) {     
            $errorMsg .= "Email is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {     
            $custemail = sanitize_input($_POST["custemail"]); // Additional check to make sure e-mail address is well-formed.     
            if (!filter_var($custemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {         
                $errorMsg .= "Invalid email format.<br>";         
                $success = false;       
            }
        } 

        if (empty($_POST["custnumber"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Contact Number is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $custnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["custnumber"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{8})$/", $custnumber)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid contact number.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $custnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["custnumber"]); 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["streetadd"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Address is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $streetadd = sanitize_input($_POST["streetadd"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9\.\-\s\,])+$/", $streetadd)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid address.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $streetadd = sanitize_input($_POST["streetadd"]); 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["blknumber"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Blk number is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $blknumber = sanitize_input($_POST["blknumber"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})$/", $blknumber)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid blk number.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $blknumber = sanitize_input($_POST["blknumber"]);  
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["unitnumber"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Unit number is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $unitnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["unitnumber"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3})$/", $unitnumber)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid unit number.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $unitnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["unitnumber"]);
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["zipcode"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Zipcode is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $zipcode = sanitize_input($_POST["zipcode"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{6})$/", $zipcode)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid zipcode.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $zipcode = sanitize_input($_POST["zipcode"]);
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["deldate"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Date is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $deldate = sanitize_input($_POST["deldate"]); 
        }

        if ($_POST["deltime"] == "0") {
            $errorMsg .= "Please select a time.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $deltime = $_POST["deltime"]; 
        }

        if (empty($_POST["ccname"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Credit card name is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $ccname = sanitize_input($_POST["ccname"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+(([a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/", $ccname)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid credit card name.<br>";     
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $ccname = sanitize_input($_POST["ccname"]);    
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["ccnumber"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Credit Card Number is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $ccnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["ccnumber"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{16})$/", $ccnumber)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid credit card number.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $ccnumber = encryptthis(sanitize_input($_POST["ccnumber"]), $key);    
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["expdate"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Exp date is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $expdate = sanitize_input($_POST["expdate"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})$/", $expdate)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid exp date.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $expdate = encryptthis(sanitize_input($_POST["expdate"]), $key);    
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["ccvnumber"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "CCV number is required.<br>";     
            $success = false; 
        } else {
            $ccvnumber = sanitize_input($_POST["ccvnumber"]); 
            if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})$/", $ccvnumber)) {
                $errorMsg .= "Please enter a valid ccv number.<br>";         
                $success = false; 
            } else {
                $ccvnumber = encryptthis(sanitize_input($_POST["ccvnumber"]), $key);    
            }
        }

         if ($success) {     
            saveCustomerInfoToDB();
            savePaymentInfoToDB();
            saveOrderToTable();
            echo "<h1>Your Order Has been Placed!</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Thank You For Your Support</h2>";    
            echo "<h3>Have A Nice Day</h3>"; 
            header('Refresh:3; url=index.php');
            exit();
        } else {    
            echo "<h1>Please check your payment input!</h1>";
            echo "<h4>The following input errors were detected:</h4>";     
            echo "<p>" . $errorMsg . "</p>"; 
            header('Refresh:3; url=payment_information.php');
        } 

        //Helper function that checks input for malicious or unwanted content. 
        function sanitize_input($data) {   
            $data = trim($data);   
            $data = stripslashes($data);   
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);   
            return $data; 
        }

        function encryptthis($data, $key) {
            $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
            $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
            return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
        }

        //Save user information into database.
        function saveCustomerInfoToDB() {  
            global $custname, $custemail, $custnumber, $streetadd, $blknumber, $unitnumber, $zipcode, $deldate, $deltime, $errorMsg; 
            // Create connection     
            $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
            // Check connection     
            if ($conn->connect_error) {            
                $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;         
            }
            else{ //prepared statement
                $compile = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer_information (name, email, mobileNumber, streetName, blkNumber, unitNumber, zipcode, deliveryDate, deliveryTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $compile->bind_param("ssisssiss", $custname, $custemail, $custnumber, $streetadd, $blknumber, $unitnumber, $zipcode, $deldate, $deltime);
                $compile->execute();
                $compile->close();
                $conn->close();
            } 
        } 

        //Save user information into database.
        function savePaymentInfoToDB() {  
            global $ccname, $ccnumber, $expdate, $ccvnumber, $errorMsg; 
            // Create connection     
            $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {            
                $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;         
            }
            else{ //prepared statement
                $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1";
                $idValue = $conn->query($sql);
                $idValueResult = $idValue->fetch_assoc();
                $customerID = $idValueResult['customer_id'];

                $compile = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer_payment_information (customer_id, fullName, creditcardNumber, expiry, ccv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");            
                $compile->bind_param("issss", $customerID, $ccname, $ccnumber, $expdate, $ccvnumber);
                $compile->execute();
                $compile->close();
                $conn->close();
            } 
        }        

        //Save user order into database.
        function saveOrderToTable() {
            session_start();
            global $errorMsg;
            $connect = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
            $array = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'];
            if ($connect->connect_error) {
                $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error;  
            } else {
                foreach ($array as $product) {
                    if($product == "") {
                        //prevent user from returning back to payment page after checkout.
                        header('Location: index.php');
                    } 
                    else {
                        //fetch primary key value
                        $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1";
                        $idValue = $connect->query($sql);
                        $idValueResult = $idValue->fetch_assoc();
                        $customerID = $idValueResult['customer_id'];

                        //prepared statement
                        $compile = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO customer_order (cust_id, productName, quantity, price, pax) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $compile->bind_param("isiii", $customerID, $product['name'],$product['quantity'], $product['price'], $product['pax']);
                        $compile->execute();
                        $compile->close();
                    }
                }
            }
            session_destroy();
            $connect->close();
        }

    ?> 
    </article>

    <?php
        include "footer.inc.php";
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There'a pattern called PRG (POST-Redirect-GET), which deals with this annoyance with the browsers' back button.

Essentially, you can POST to your page, do your thing, then redirect to a second page which will not perform the action again.

Here's a decent article explaining it in more detail.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks. actually from you link I found if I use exist(); it works perfectly welll.

Comment: Glad i could help, can you mark this the answer please then?

Answer (score 0):

After the checkout add this:

```php
<?php
header("Location: /index.php");
exit();
```

The location header tells the browser to redirect, exit stops the script execution, also beware that if you have sent any output to browser (e.g. `echo` or the html code you have on top), it won't work.

You should handle the checkout separately where nothing is sent to the browser.

You could for example create a separate file with your checkout code that you will include right before the `<html>` tag, then if nothing is submitted, just do nothing in the script, if the form is submitted, handle it and then do the redirect.

Comment: Do i add this to the if($sucess) part or at the top of my payment.php file ?
Because I did add this lines into the code, however the I could still return back to the payment page.

Comment: Move the whole code that deals with $_POST handling to a separate file that's included before any html content. That way you don't mix functional and presentational data. Let's say you will have two files: `payment.php` and `payment-process.php`. The `payment.php` will only use code that shows data to the user - e.g. define html, include header etc. and the `payment-process.php` will handle the post data and process the payment.

Comment: yes, the code I posted is the "payment_process.php" not the payment.php that contain the GUI

Comment: So what I did was, if all information is validated and submitted to the database, I will redirect the user to index.php and I have added the exist();

Comment: However, I am still able to return back to the payment page

Comment: You can always go back, that's a browser function. I think you could do a redirect to the same page, the browser will then replace the page in history with the reloaded one and you will be unable to resubmit the form by going back.

Comment: That is the issue, the form stills contain the information the user has entered and I am able to submit the form again, despite the cart being empty.

Comment: As I said, do a redirect to the same page, e.g. a reload, so if your page has url `/payment.php`, do `header("Location: /payment.php");exit;`.

Comment: sorry but why would I want to redirect to the same payment page ? After the validation and if it is success -> redirect back to main page -> exit;

Comment: however, as I have said, I have tried it. But I am still able to press back to the payment page, not only that but the payment information is still on the form despite having checkout.